# Glowing text on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a glowing text menu in jQuery and after a lot of hard work it's still not working. I don't know where my mistake is... Could anyone help me?

HTML:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="glow Text">HOME</div>
    <div class="glow Text">CONTACT</div>
    <div class="glow Text">PRODUCTS</div>
    <div class="glow Text">SERVICES</div>
    <div class="glow Text">BLOG</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background:#000
}
#list .glow{
    text-shadow: #CCC 0px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
}
#list .active{
    position:relative;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.glow').glow();
})
```

Comment: After re-indenting your code I found that your body has a CSS property that doesn't close. Place a semi-colon behind `#000`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what your jQuery is doing. But I can see the CSS is wrong. Your `.glow` class has:

```
text-shadow: #CCC 0px 0px 0px;
```

This means: draw a shadow of color `#CCC` with (`0px`, `0px`) offset and `0px` blur radius.

Since the shadow is drawn without offset **and** without blur, the shadow is drawn exactly at the same place of the normal text.

To fix this, either add a blur radius (makes it *glow-y*)

```
text-shadow: #CCC 0px 0px 4px;
```

or a shadow offset (less *glow-y*):

```
text-shadow: #CCC 2px 4px 0px;
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. See [here](http://jsbin.com/UGoxifI/1/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Just add a `:hover` on `.glow` class, as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/UGoxifI/4/edit)

Comment: @friendy As Beteraraba says: CSS has :hover pseudo-classes. This means the class will only be applied when the mouse hovers above the element. It's a really powerful feature!

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but have you double checked to make sure that jquery is definately loading into your site correctly?

Best way to make sure is to use the google link that i normally use.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure it's on the header BEFORE any jquery calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you want to use jquery for this? According to me you can do this with CSS only, which is a better way to go.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+glow